# Docker file permission php on Mac OS with docker-compose && dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, boot2docker

I need a help about file permissions on my docker project.
I'm using docker-compose + dockerfile and I'm having a problem that my php can`t write files in my projects, so I can`t develope. Here is my project

https://github.com/marcoaure/my-php-docker/tree/16c1a69952ba57fb18b8de275f19ee8d3899054e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

Comment: thanks for comment, i'm having a problem with cach in docker-compose, after I resolv it I will answer if it works.

Comment: Hello brother it works with this adds:
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data
RUN usermod -G staff www-data
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html